# sublime text 3 настройки отображения папки

Tags: sublime-text-3

Мне нужно чтобы пробел "ребенка" был больше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например в данном случае .idea перемещается вправо совсем на чуть-чуть.
Как мне это увеличить?